# Observing conditions across multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, observer-pattern, modeling

I'm building a flow whereby a user can administer an event, specifically doing the following:

- Register attendees
- Attach photos
- Attach fitness information

Each of these currently happens in a seperate controller, and can happen in any order.

Having completed all three, I'd then like to generate an email out to all attendees with links ot the photos, etc.

I'm having trouble finding the best approach to check against the three conditions listed above.  Currently, I'm approaching it by creating a service called GenerateEmailsToAttendees with a method .try.  This checks against the conditions, and if all are met, generates the emails: e.g:

```
class GenerateEmailsToAttendees

  def try(event)
    if event.has_some_fitness_activities? and event.has_some_attendees? and event.has_some_photos?
      event.attendances.each do |attendance|
        attendance.notify_user_about_write_up
      end
    end
  end

end
```

The problem now is that I have this GenerateEmailsToAttendees scattered across three controllers (AttendeesController#register, PhotosController#attach and FitnessInfoController#attach). I also run the risk of duplicating the notifications to the users.

Is there a better way?  Could I use an observer to watch for the three conditions being met?

I can provide more information on the model structure if it's useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about moving your observer to a cron job? i.e: remove it from all three controllers, and just put it in a rake task and schedule it to run every week/day/hour etc on all events that have met the conditions. You should probably set a flag on the event if the email has been generated so you don't spam the same user twice. I understand that this might not be *realtime* but it'll definitely solve your problem. I would recommend using https://github.com/javan/whenever for managing your cronjobs.

Answer (score 0):

I would put this into an after_save callback:  then Rails will just take care of it automatically. You will probably need some system to ensure that this only happens once.  I would do something like this:

- add a new boolean field to track whether the event has all of the required "stuff" done in order to send out the email, eg "published"
- when the various things that can make an event "published" happen, call a method in the Event model which tests if the event is ready to be published and currently NOT published: if it is, then update the model to be published and send the email.

eg - (i'm guessing at your join table names here)

```
#app/models/event_attendance.rb

after_create :is_event_publishable?

def is_event_publishable?
  self.event.publishable?
end

#app/models/event_fitness_activity.rb

after_create :is_event_publishable?

def is_event_publishable?
  self.event.publishable?
end

#app/models/event_photo.rb

after_create :is_event_publishable?

def is_event_publishable?
  self.event.publishable?
end

#app/models/event.rb

def publishable?
 if !self.published && self.fitness_activities.size > 0 and self.attendences.size > 0 and self.photos.size > 0
    self.attendances.each do |attendance|
      attendance.notify_user_about_write_up
    end
  end  
end
```

Now you don't need anything to do with this at all in your controllers.  Generally i'm in favour of keeping controllers as absolutely standard as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create an observer that watches multiple models with a single 'after_save' callback using something like

```
observe :account, :balance
def after_save(record)
  make your checks here
end
```